# Persist entire class as JSON using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have found many examples of how to persist an individual member of an entity as JSON, but what about if I want the entire class persisted as JSON?  For example, if I have a class:

```
    public class MyObj
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public int[] Array {get; set;}
    }
```

and I want it persisted in the database as:

```
Table: MyObjTable
Row 1:
  Id: 1
  MyObj: {"id": 1, "array": [1, 2, 3]}
Row 2:
  Id: 2
  MyObj: {"id": 2, "array": [4, 5, 6]}
```

What would the DbContext class look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really about the DbContext class.  You'd need to provide a property getter and setter for "MyObj" and prevent mapping of Array:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int[] Array { get; set; }
    
    public string Obj
    {
         get
         {
             return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
         }
         set
         {
             MyObj clone = JsonSerialiser.Deserialize<MyObj>(value);
             Array = clone.Array;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was hoping to avoid having to do.  My data object has many properties and I don't want to clutter it with EF stuff.  I guess the solution is to create a separate entity class for my data object that just has the ID and JSON string of the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait until **November 2021**, then you are able to use a native feature available in **EF Core 6 (.NET 6.0)**. By then properties can be decorated with a `JsonColumn` (name can be different until release). Complex (and also simple / primitive) values can then be serialized into json within a column in the database. You can read more in the [devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-plan-for-entity-framework-core-6-0/).

Comment: But that would only help me persist individual members as JSON.  I'm interested in persisting the entire class as JSON.